# Hide main nav and only show it on specific category pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A site I'm working on has 3 brands, so will require 3 different sets of navigation.

What I'm trying to do is show a specific menu id on each of the category pages.

E.g.

```
#CSmainMenu to display only when its on www.site.com/caroline-sills/
#SillsmainMenu to display only when its on www.site/com/sills/
#ClopemainMenu to display only when its on www.site/calliope/
```

For the rest of the site, those 3 menus are not to be seen elsewhere, such as the home page, about, and any other static pages.

I've tried setting up one, but I'm having no luck.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#CSmainMenu").hide(); 
  });

  if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("/caroline-sills/") == 0) {     
    $("#CSmainMenu").show();
  }
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does this code hide the menu ? 
I mean is hiding works ? 
if yes , I'll give your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#CSmainMenu").hide();
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("/category1/") !== -1)
{
    $("#CSmainMenu").show();
}
    if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("/category2/") !== -1)
    {
        $("#CSmainMenu2").show();
    }        
});
```

Comment: this works but how do i hide #CSmainMenu2 on load do i add a comma like this $(document).ready(function() { $("#CSmainMenu" , "#CSmainMenu2").hide(); if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("/category1/") !== -1) { $("#CSmainMenu").show(); } if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("/category2/") !== -1) { $("#CSmainMenu2").show(); } });

Comment: No. Put functions in seprate lines, like this:


        $("#CSmainMenu").hide();
        $("#CSmainMenu2").hide();

Comment: i gave this a go but only hiding the #CSmainMenu, please see my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

if your pathname is correct, i think you just messed up the brace. 
Try to put the if-statement inside the jquery.ready function, like i did in the example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#CSmainMenu").hide();
  if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("/js") == 0) { $("#CSmainMenu").show(); }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="CSmainMenu">CSMainMenu</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(){
        $("#CSmainMenu").hide(); 
   if (window.location.pathname.replace('/',"") =="caroline-sills") { $("#CSmainMenu").show(); }

       })();

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do DOM manipulations through JS can you not add a class to the body for each specific page and hide/style the nav through CSS? This would be a much faster and efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i got it working, i figured out that there was a "-" missing from the second pathname.indexOf value

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jq(document).ready(function() {
    jq("#CSmainMenu").hide();  
    jq("#SillsmainMenu").hide();
if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("/caroline-sills/") !== -1)
{
    jq("#CSmainMenu").show();
}
    if (window.location.pathname.indexOf("/sills/") !== -1)
    {
        jq("#SillsmainMenu").show();
    }        
});
</script>
```

Thanks again